# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin for https

Tags: angular, express, amazon-cloudfront

I have a two part app,

- an https api server on aws eb, using cloudfront
- an https aws s3 angular front end, using cloudfront

I have set `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` in the API app.js, and can access the API manually without a problem.

However when using the webapp I get the following error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present.`

It worked when I was using http, but using https from cloudfront distributions I get the error.

Any help or pointers of what to read would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide all error detail on your client.

Comment: What web server did you use to host the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the origin returns the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header by running a curl command similar to the following:

`curl -H "origin: example.com" -v "https://api.example.com/hello"`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 01 May 2018 03:06:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3770
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 01:50:52 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "58c9ef7c-eba"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Second, Check to see if the cloudfront distributions to allow `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS` http methods.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/

Comment: my guess would be your issue is in the cloudfront configuration

Comment: one more point, make sure to include the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` with your API's error responses as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My first time using AWS. I hadn't enabled the methods in cloudfront. So many things to overlook!